# Selenium Python getting around "Open <...>.app?"

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, ui-automation, slack

I am trying to write e2e tests for a Slack bot and while logging in via browser it always asks whether I'd like to use the Slack desktop app instead of continuing with the browser (its Chrome by the way). Steps the Selenium webdriver is performing:

1. Visit `https://company-name.slack.com`
2. Fill in the `email` and `password`
3. Click `Sign In` button
4. Then this shows up:

[image: Open Slack.app Pop-Up]

This is not a normal browser alert but I'd like to get rid of it. I have tried the following:

1. `webdriver.switch_to.alert.dismiss()` Does not dismiss this pop-up
2. Adding the `chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-default-apps')` switch also doesn't prevent the pop-up from showing
3. Have tried the headless version as well, test failure suggests that the pop-up interrupted the flow.

This also has to work on CI servers so please if the solution didn't involve modifying developer machine then that would be wonderful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is not an answer but a workaround. I managed to get around the `default-app` pop-up by continuing my operations in a new tab (But not before checking whether there is a pop-up in the first place). Psuedo code:

```
try
    find_element_by_whatever(element_you_expect_after_login)
catch TimeoutException
    webdriver.execute_script('window.open()')
    webdriver.switch_to.window(webdriver.window_handles[1])
    webdriver.get(url_which_required_login_in_the_first_place)
```

Answer (score 1):

today I solved this problem, you can just simply install pynput module, after that :

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
keyboard = Controller()

keyboard.press(Key.enter)
keyboard.release(Key.enter)
```

you can handle the open app popup in selenium with your keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

try this `chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")` or `chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-window")` or create a code for click the cancel button to do the next operation.

Comment: The two arguments you provided doesn't get rid of the popup in question. I was actually asking help for the code that you are suggesting that I write. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If this alert pops up every time you run the test, and the `Cancel` button is always in focus, then you can try to send the driver an `ENTER`.

Comment: Tried this:

    `key_action = ActionChains(webdriver) -> key_action.send_keys(Keys.ENTER) -> key_action.perform()`

Doesn't dismiss the pop-up

Comment: Are you sure the popup is present when the ENTER is sent? Perhaps the send_key method is performed before the javascript finishes behind the alert dialog... That reminds me of a possible solution :) Can you identify and disable the javascript that pops up the alert dialog?

Comment: Yeah, the `send_key` is happening within a while loop (with stdout logs) and I'm monitoring the logs as well as the screen, so I'm pretty sure `ENTER` doesn't cancel the popup. The _disable JavaScript_ sounds promising though